# How can I use plugins in Akka.net

Tags: c#, akka, actor

I would like to know. How can I use plugins in [Akka.net](http://getakka.net/)? For example, I would like to make a plugin to work with database.

I have a few questions:

1. How can I load a plugin to my app?
2. How can I configure a plugin. I mean I am using MVVM in my application. How can I send the settings from MVVM to the plugin?

**Update**

I would like to make a client server application. Where the client is mvvm desktop app and the server is a windows service. How to make so that user can select and configure the plugins on mvvm client. I mean the user has a window (This image I just found on the Internet it image shows what I want to do) in this window user can select and configure plugin.

[image]
Question.

How to send (install on the server) selected in the client plugin, and how to send to the server settings if the client changed them after installing the plugin.

Comment: I don't know about Akka.net but *How can I load a plugin to my app?* has been asked several times. Also at the moment we aren't sure about what are you asking in your question 2

Comment: I am interested in a matter of loading plug-in the context of Akka.net   
I know how to work with plugins in "classic" desktop app but how to work with plugins in Akka.net I can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins in Akka.NET are essentially singleton objects that are associated with an `ActorSystem`.

We use them for things like Cluster and Persistence support, that is, pluggable features of the Akka.NET stack.

When you say "plugin to work with database", we do have Akka.Persistence for eventsourcing support.
http://getakka.net/docs/Persistence

Is that what you are looking for?

If you just want to use a database from within an actor, just use any standard dataaccess code in a message handler.
There is no need for a plugin in order to talk to entity framework or similar.

The question is quite unclear.

What exactly is it that you want your plugin to do?